# SKAction on SKLabel with array of Strings

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have an SKLabel attached to a parent SKNode and an array of strings:

```
let configText:[String] = [
                            "Configuration",
                             "Do stuff",
                             "Do more stuff",
                             "Nil",
                             "It is the void"]
```

The array is looped through with the following:

```
parentNode_Label.run(
  SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.run{
      if self.counter == self.configText.count - 1
      { self.counter = 0 } },
    SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0),
    SKAction.run { self.sprite_Label.text = self.configText[self.counter + 1] },
    SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.5),
    SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0),
    SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.5),
    SKAction.run{ self.counter += 1 }
    ]).forever()
)

extension SKAction
public func forever() -> SKAction { return SKAction.repeatForever( self ) }
}
```

It works but seems kind of clunky/hacky. Is there a simpler, more efficient yet readable way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first array element `configText[0]` is never used, so you can
  remove it from the array (and modify the index calculations accordingly).
- Incrementing the counter with wrap-around can be simplified using the
  remainder operator:

  ```
  self.counter = (self.counter + 1) % self.configText.count
  ```
- The three "run" actions can be combined into one.
- Inside the actions array you can refer to the `SKAction` members
  without specifying the type explicitly, e.g. `.wait` instead 
  of `SKAction.wait`.

Putting it all together:

```
parentNode_Label.run(
    SKAction.sequence([
        .wait(forDuration: 3.0),
        .run {
            self.sprite_Label.text = self.configText[self.counter]
            self.counter = (self.counter + 1) % self.configText.count
        },
        .fadeIn(withDuration: 0.5),
        .wait(forDuration: 3.0),
        .fadeOut(withDuration: 0.5),
        ]).forever()
)
```

Also have a look at the [Swift naming conventions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines):

> Names of types and protocols are UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.

For example: `parentNode`, `textLabel`, without underscores.